# Is there a way to push a git tag using lerna without bumping up any version?

Tags: git, lerna, monorepo

Is there a way to push a git tag using lerna without bumping up any version/without pushing any commit?

I want to run a command from my CI machine where it tags a particular commit with a static string like 'ReleasedToProd' post the deployment.

There are multiple versions published in every sprint using lerna and one of the versions will be released at the end of sprint. How can I tag this version with a static string using the existing lerna setup?

I want to achieve the below things using lerna setup
`git tag ReleasedToProd`
`git push --tags`

Answer (score 0):

The normal command is [`lerna publish`](https://lernajs.io/#command-publish), but it does bump the version.

I am not sure you would find a native lerna command, but you do have examples:

- [`__tests__/git-tag.test.js`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/8c2843f00e4a95359e3badf5a88927947a45cf2d/commands/version/__tests__/git-tag.test.js) shows how to apply a tag

  ```
  const tag = "v1.2.3";
  const opts = { cwd: "default" };
  await gitTag(tag, {}, opts);
  ```
- [`__tests__/git-push.test.js`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/8c2843f00e4a95359e3badf5a88927947a45cf2d/commands/version/__tests__/git-push.test.js) show a tag, commit and call to [`git push --follow-tag`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/86017d769bb83dfd1abb88f4cf560f73651ad494/commands/version/lib/git-push.js)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the answer. How do I use the `gitPush` command with lerna? Can you help me understand more?

Comment: @ShridharKalagi By making a javascript similar to those I reference in the answer: Any command like for example `lerna publish` (https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/2c925bde7f0a062e1847a6b369efde61acd2419d/commands/publish) is a similar script: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/2c925bde7f0a062e1847a6b369efde61acd2419d/commands/publish/index.js